# Multiple definition of '***' while building Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I recently upgrade to Bazel `0.19.0` and get the following error while trying to build Tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
tensorflow multiple definition of 'pb_ostream_from_buffer'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

where the `...` represents more errors of the form `multiple definition of '***'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bazel `0.19.0` no longer reads from `tools/bazel.rc`. One option in that file (`--define=grpc_no_ares=true`) is needed.

You can instead include it on the CLI:

```
bazel build --define=grpc_no_ares=true --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

This problem is detailed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23402).